# MFC Print Preview bug in CPreviewView

Tags: c++, mfc

I reckon I've found a bug in MFC class `CPreviewView` and just want to see if anyone else has it. When generating a preview for a document with 2 or more pages, and the 2-page preview 'mode' is set, the scrollbars are set as if it was the 1-page preview. This means that for a 2-page document (say) (again showing in 2-page preview mode) that the scroll bars are shown (they shouldn't) and the user can scroll down to "page 3" and p1 is then regenerated.

I think the problem lies in `viewprev.cpp` around L393:

```
m_nPages = m_pPreviewInfo->m_nNumPreviewPages;
if (m_nPages == 0)
    m_nPages = 1;
else if (m_nPages > m_nMaxPages)
    m_nPages = m_nMaxPages;     // Sanity Check!

m_nZoomOutPages = m_nPages;

SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT, CSize(1, 1));   // initialize mapping mode only

if (m_pPreviewInfo->GetMaxPage() < 0x8000 &&
    m_pPreviewInfo->GetMaxPage() - m_pPreviewInfo->GetMinPage() <= 32767U)
{
    SCROLLINFO info;
    info.fMask = SIF_PAGE|SIF_RANGE;
    info.nMin = m_pPreviewInfo->GetMinPage();
    info.nMax = m_pPreviewInfo->GetMaxPage();
    info.nPage = 1;
    if (!SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT, &info, FALSE))
        SetScrollRange(SB_VERT, info.nMin, info.nMax, FALSE);
}
else
    ShowScrollBar(SB_VERT, FALSE);      // if no range specified, or too
                                        // large don't show
```

Surely this excerpt should have:

```
info.nMax = m_pPreviewInfo->GetMaxPage() - (m_nPages - 1) ;
```

instead.

Is the solution to derive my own and override this function as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aabc3hc6.aspx#sthash.aKlh2DG4.dpuf?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of MFC are you using?

Comment: Silly of me not to include - VS2013 so MFC 12